# Knapsack problem: Optimal fair division of items in limited quantity, between Knapsacks with unlimited capacity

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I am looking for a solution to the following Knapsack problem:

1. **Dynamic programming** and not naive programming, in **C++**
2. For each item, **weight and value are equal**, meaning no two arrays are needed, but only one. Therefore we will refer to weights only.
3. There are **three knapsack**. All of them have **no capacity weight limit**, which means that all the items **must** be taken, but also the distribution between the bags **must** be as fair as possible (optimal).

Attached is a solution I wrote for the above problem with **two knapsacks**. It works properly, but long and complicated. For three knapsack I got completely entangled.

I would be happy, but not necessary:

1. A simpler solution than what I wrote
2. If there is a solution for the unlimited amount of knapsack (of course must meet all the above conditions
   )
3. As in my solution, print which items will be in each bag (In addition to the weight difference between the knapsacks)

I know and apologize. The explanation for the solution I wrote is long. I will explain it, but **there is no need for the solution I am asking for to be necessarily similar to what I wrote**.

Explanation of the solution I wrote:

Each cell of the table has a pair of numbers - the first knapsack and the second knapsack.

The columns represent all possible weights from 0 to the total weight of all the items. The rows represent the weight of each item.

In each cell we want to fill in the table, we will see if there are two options:

1. If there a cell above it
2. If it is possible to step back from it (left) the amount of cells as the amount of weight represented in the current row and then go up one cell up

From the above existing options, we will select the maximum weight of the first knapsack and place it in the current cell in the first knapsack. In the second knapsack of the current cell we will set the difference.

Then, if the weight in the current cell can be added to the first knapsack, without the addition exceeding the weight represented by the current column we will add, otherwise we will add the weight to the second knapsack.

In the last line we will find the optimal solution, according to the pair of numbers with the lowest difference between them. From that cell we can step back and find out how the optimal solution was obtained.

**My C++ code solution for two knapsacks**

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// 2 knapsacks
int *items_arr,
    items_num,
    ***knapsacks_arr, // [row][col][knapsack]
    rows,
    cols;

void allocate_knapsacks_arr()
{
    knapsacks_arr = new int **[rows];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        knapsacks_arr[r] = new int *[cols];
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            knapsacks_arr[r][c] = new int[2]; // 2 knapsacks
    }
}

void delete_knapsacks_arr()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
            delete[] knapsacks_arr[r][c];
        delete[] knapsacks_arr[r];
    }
    delete[] knapsacks_arr;
}

void initialize_knapsacks_arr()
{
    knapsacks_arr[0][0][0] = 0;
    knapsacks_arr[0][0][1] = 0;
    for (int c = 1; c < cols; c++)
    {
        knapsacks_arr[0][c][0] = INT_MAX;
        knapsacks_arr[0][c][1] = INT_MAX;
    }

    int sum_items = 0,
        index_items = 0;
    for (int c, r = 1; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c <= sum_items + items_arr[index_items]; c++)
        {
            // set knapsacks1
            int k1_up = knapsacks_arr[r - 1][c][0];
            int k1_left = INT_MAX;
            if (c >= items_arr[index_items])
                k1_left = knapsacks_arr[r - 1][c - items_arr[index_items]][0];

            // if no up and no left
            if (k1_up == INT_MAX && k1_left == INT_MAX)
                knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] = 0;

            // if only up
            if (k1_up != INT_MAX && k1_left == INT_MAX)
                knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] = k1_up;

            // if only left
            if (k1_up == INT_MAX && k1_left != INT_MAX)
                knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] = k1_left;

            // if up and left
            if (k1_up != INT_MAX && k1_left != INT_MAX)
            {
                if (k1_up > k1_left)
                    knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] = k1_up;
                else
                    knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] = k1_left;
            }

            // set knapsacks2
            knapsacks_arr[r][c][1] = sum_items - knapsacks_arr[r][c][0];

            // add item
            if (c >= knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] + items_arr[index_items])
                knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] += items_arr[index_items];
            else
                knapsacks_arr[r][c][1] += items_arr[index_items];
        }
        for (; c < cols; c++)
        {
            knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] = INT_MAX;
            knapsacks_arr[r][c][1] = INT_MAX;
        }
        sum_items += items_arr[index_items];
        index_items++;
    }
}

void show_knapsacks_arr()
{
    cout << "\t";
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        cout << c << "\t";
    cout << endl;

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        if (r > 0)
            cout << items_arr[r - 1];
        cout << "\t";

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            cout << "(";
            if (knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] == INT_MAX) // == numeric_limits<int>::max()
                cout << "-";                       // static_cast<unsigned char>(236);
            else
                cout << knapsacks_arr[r][c][0];
            cout << ", ";
            if (knapsacks_arr[r][c][1] == INT_MAX)
                cout << "-"; // static_cast<unsigned char>(236);
            else
                cout << knapsacks_arr[r][c][1];
            cout << ")\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int items_sum()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < items_num; i++)
        sum += items_arr[i];
    return sum;
}

void show_optimal_solution(int r, int c)
{
    int index_items = items_num;

    cout << "Dynamic (2D array)" << endl
         << "optimal difference = " << abs(knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] - knapsacks_arr[r][c][1]) << endl
         << "knapsack 1 total weight of all items = " << knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] << endl
         << "knapsack 2 total weight of all items = " << knapsacks_arr[r][c][1] << endl;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << endl
             << "item number " << index_items << ", weight = " << items_arr[index_items - 1] << ", indexes = (" << r << ", " << c << ") >> ";
        if (r == 1)
        {
            if (c < items_arr[0])
                cout << "knapsack 2";
            else
                cout << "knapsack 1";
            cout << endl
                 << endl;
            return;
        }
        if (knapsacks_arr[r][c][0] == knapsacks_arr[r - 1][c][0])
        {
            cout << "knapsack 2";
            r--;
            index_items--;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "knapsack 1";
            r--;
            c -= items_arr[index_items - 1];
            index_items--;
        }
    }
}

void find_optimal_solutions()
{
    // find minimum difference between each pair knapsacks in last row
    int optimal = INT_MAX,
        index = 0;
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    {
        int tmp = abs(knapsacks_arr[rows - 1][c][0] - knapsacks_arr[rows - 1][c][1]);
        if (optimal > tmp)
        {
            optimal = tmp;
            index = c;
        }
    }
    show_optimal_solution(rows - 1, index); // only first solution

    // find all same differences in last row = additional solutions
    // for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    //  if (optimal == abs(knapsacks_arr[rows - 1][c][0] - knapsacks_arr[rows - 1][c][1]))
    //      show_optimal_solution(rows - 1, c);
}

int main()
{
    items_arr = new int[]{7, 3, 1, 6};
    items_num = 4;

    rows = items_num + 1;
    cols = items_sum() + 1;

    allocate_knapsacks_arr();
    initialize_knapsacks_arr();
    show_knapsacks_arr();
    find_optimal_solutions();
    delete_knapsacks_arr();
    delete[] items_arr;

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

weights 7, 3, 1, 6

**Output**

first knapsack: 1, 7

second knapsack: 6, 4

```
        0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17    
        (0, 0)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)
7       (0, 7)  (0, 7)  (0, 7)  (0, 7)  (0, 7)  (0, 7)  (0, 7)  (7, 0)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)
3       (0, 10) (0, 10) (0, 10) (3, 7)  (3, 7)  (3, 7)  (3, 7)  (7, 3)  (3, 7)  (3, 7)  (10, 0) (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)
1       (0, 11) (1, 10) (1, 10) (3, 8)  (4, 7)  (4, 7)  (4, 7)  (7, 4)  (8, 3)  (4, 7)  (10, 1) (11, 0) (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)  (-, -)
6       (0, 17) (1, 16) (1, 16) (3, 14) (4, 13) (4, 13) (4, 13) (7, 10) (8, 9)  (4, 13) (10, 7) (11, 6) (10, 7) (13, 4) (14, 3) (10, 7) (16, 1) (17, 0)

Dynamic (2D array)
optimal difference = 1
knapsack 1 total weight of all items = 8
knapsack 2 total weight of all items = 9

item number 4, weight = 6, indexes = (4, 8) >> knapsack 2
item number 3, weight = 1, indexes = (3, 8) >> knapsack 1
item number 2, weight = 3, indexes = (2, 7) >> knapsack 2
item number 1, weight = 7, indexes = (1, 7) >> knapsack 1
```

Comment: I would start by using the proper header files (not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`), and use `std::vector` instead of all of those pointers.  Using `std::vector` would reduce the current code you have by a substantial amount.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie

In retrospect, I have already written the solution for two knapsacks in arrays, but in the first place, of course you are right.

Comment: *Attached is a solution I wrote for the above problem with two knapsacks* -- In your solution, you hardcoded a `2` when allocating.  What is the issue if you changed this to `3`?  If you cannot work with a varying amount like this, then your original solution should have been written with `n` knapsacks in mind.  I think that was your intention, but you may have painted yourself into a corner concentrating on `2`, and thus wrote the entire rest of the code assuming only 2.

Comment: [Here is your solution, using vector](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e3aa94faf556b340).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
Thanks for the solution using vectors. Unfortunately it is not enough to change the hardcode from 2 to 3. The algorithm I wrote only works on two knapsacks.

Comment: Well, you have to start over with a new plan, but this time, think of `n`, not 2 or 3.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
I'm not sure it's that simple, therefore I asked for a solution for 3 knapsacks. But if there is a simple solution for n knapsacks, of course it is better.

Comment: *I'm not sure it's that simple* -- Never said it was simple.  You need to go back to pencil and paper, start over, but think of `n`, and not a specific number.  The issue is that possibly, the solution is radically different than the code you posted, so probably there is very little to work with in the existing code.  This is the dilemma when a programmer jumps into writing a solution, finds it works for their scenario, and when it comes time to generalize it, they have to tear the whole thing down and start over.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie

According to the solutions I have found so far for similar problems, it is necessary to add another dimension to the array (or to the vector) for each knapsack, which means that it is not certain that a solution for n knapsacks can be written.

Comment: *which means that it is not certain that a solution for n knapsacks can be written* -- Come on now.  C++ is used to write operating systems, computer-aided design programs, game engines, word processors, control microwave ovens.  So you're saying there is no solution that can be written for n knapsacks?  There is one, you just haven't found it yet.  Also, if you narrowed your research down to "how to create a varying number of dimensions in C++" or similar query, you will probably find hundreds, if not thousands of examples, maybe advanced, but possible.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie

Ok, if there is a solution for n of course I would love to have it. If there is a solution for 3, maybe we can learn from it how to make it n.

Comment: Note: this problem is known more precisely as [Fair SSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_subset_sum).

Comment: Thank for the note @gudok